# telerik treeview force requery database

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, treeview

I'm new to telerik components and I'm figuring out how to bind it to a database,
what I have done already is correctly connecting the tree view to my table and getting data correctly on form load.
now somehow I know a new row has been inserted in the database, but I can not figure out how to force the tree view to requery the database and load new changes.

I had no luck using obvious methods such as `radTreeView1.ResetBindings();`
 and `radTreeView1.Refresh();`

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try re-assigning `DataSource` property of TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

If the data has changed and you'd like to refresh the treview, you can try re-assigning the DataSource as mentioned by @Muhammad, then call the DataBind() method.

See [Databinding Properties and Methods](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/treeview/data-binding/overview#databinding-properties-and-methods)

```cs
radTreeView1.DataSource = getFreshdata();
radTreeView1.DataBind();
```